# Using a sequencing variable to name a record?

Tags: c#

I would like to use my variable `i` (that is used to sequence a loop) to name a record. This in order to know both how many of these records I have and to be able to loop through each one in a `for` loop.

This is how I have tried to do it:

```
while (UserValue != "none")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Input a product Name or type \"none\" to exit.");
    UserValue = Console.ReadLine();
    if (UserValue == "none")
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Input this products value in Pounds.");
    products i = new(UserValue, float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    i = i + 1;
  }
```

I'm not even sure if it is possible so if it isn't, any alternative solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your whole loop to help provide context around its instantiation and any value setting?

Comment: You are referring to a loop, but your code does not show any

Comment: Also please provide code which will compile.

Comment: If you want " to be able to loop through each one in a for loop.", you can create a *collection*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you want a *collection*, say `List<T>` of items, e.g.

```
//TODO: decimal is better if "value" stands for money
// I used named tuple here, but you may want an elaborated custom class
var products = new List<(string name, float value)>();

// Keep asking user to input products until "none" is given
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Input a product Name or type \"none\" to exit.");

  UserValue = Console.ReadLine();
  
  //TODO: trim spaces and, probably, use case insensitive check
  if (UserValue == "none")
    break;

  Console.WriteLine("Input this products value in Pounds.");

  //TODO: float.TryParse is a better option
  products.Add((UserValue, float.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
}
```

then having collection you can loop over it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; ++i) {
  (string name, float value) = products[i];

  ...
}
```

or

```
foreach (var (name, value) in products) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better strategy is using a `List<products>`. Also, rename the `products` class to just `product`:

```
var allProducts = new List<product>();

// ...

Console.WriteLine("Input a product Name or type \"none\" to exit.");
UserValue = Console.ReadLine();
if (UserValue == "none")
    break;
Console.WriteLine("Input this product's value in Pounds.");
allProducts.Add(new product(UserValue, float.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
```

You can still loop over this `allProducts` list with either a `for` loop (look at the `.Count` property of the list) or a `foreach` loop.